# How can I create a new pandas column with row numbers splited by Index values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe with row number  + 1, splited (reset) for each value of the index.

I have already tried to reset_index() and then index value and groupby cumcount

```
test['day'] = teste.reset_index().groupby(['field','chunk']).cumcount()+1
```

but they returned a count from first row to the last one of the entire dataframe.

The result I get

```
          value dia
field chunk                             
Vista 10.17 520.0 1
Vista 10.17 360.0 2
Vista 10.17 430.0 3
Vista 10.18 450.0 4
Vista 10.18 650.0 5
Vista 10.18 750.0 6
```

The result I want

```
          value dia
field chunk                             
Vista 10.17 520.0 1
Vista 10.17 360.0 2
Vista 10.17 430.0 3
Vista 10.18 450.0 1
Vista 10.18 650.0 2
Vista 10.18 750.0 3
```

Comment: Please add sample input, expected output

Comment: I suspect there is some indexing mis-alignment going on. Try this: `test['day'] = test.reset_index().groupby(['field','chunk']).cumcount().gt(1).values`

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thank you. Just edited with some results

Comment: @Hugo, great could you add the input too?

Comment: @DanielMesejo The input is the data without column `dia`

Comment: @Hugo I am not able to reproduce your error here, the code you posted gives me the right results

Comment: It works as @DanielMesejo told.

Comment: @Hugo I have addressed your question in my comment, did you overlook it?

Comment: @Coldspeed I am sorry. I used your sugestion without `gt(1)` and it works

Comment: `test['day'] = test.reset_index().groupby(['field','chunk']).cumcount().values+1`